# Why does Rails redeclare js variable with link_to, but not on reload?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 7 app with Ruby 3.

I have the following in my index.html.erb

```
<script>
    const chart_data = <%= sanitize @transactions %>;
</script>
```

If I access index.html.erb from a link_to tag, the console says:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: redeclaration of const chart_data
```

But if I reload the page, it works fine.

Why does reloading the page fix the js variable redeclaration issue?

Comment: You are using https://turbo.hotwired.dev/ which is bundled by default with Rails